# Non-zero files display as 0 KB in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, ntfs

Some files shows "0 KB" in explorer's size column on Windows Server 2012R2, but they have content and show non-zero size in file's properties popup. They can be correctly opened.

These files sit on a NTFS volume, and were initially uploaded by a remote program via SFTP, to FreeFTPd on the Windows Server

The wrong size can be fixed by copying the file to anywhere, or downloading it via WinSCP and then refreshing.

The FreeFTPd is the latest version, and Windows Server is updated two or three months ago.

It seems like that the size information is not synchronized among Windows components.

What are most possible causes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How large actually are the files?

Comment: Question: Are you on Windows Server? Try: (1) Rename the file to anything else, (2) `chkdsk /f` (ensure you have backups).

Comment: @Mokubai,  less than 200KB,  many are 4~8KB. The file system block size is 4KB.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks for your advise. Yes, it's on Win Server 2012R2 in EC2. Tried to rename but failed due to in using by the FTPServer, and after failure the size number got fixed for that single file.
Tried chkdsk (without f option, since now the volume cannot be unmounted), and no error found.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons for such files:

- Files being stored by non-Windows software
- Files "optimized" by
  [Data Deduplication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/data-deduplication/understand),
  available only on Windows Server.

The files involved are correct on the disk and the data is safe for most operations.

In the first case, almost any operation that causes Windows to refresh the file's
metadata will cause the real size to be displayed. For example, renaming the file
will fix the displayed size.

For the second case, De-duplication can be disabled on the disk, except that
disabling Data De-duplication doesn’t "undupe" the data already "duped".

See the article
[Disabling Data Deduplication on Windows Server 2012R2](https://nickwhittome.com/2014/10/01/disabling-data-deduplication-on-windows-server-2012r2/)
for the procedure to follow using the PowerShell command
[Start-DedupJob](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/deduplication/start-dedupjob?view=win10-ps):

> The unoptimise command:
>
> ```
> start-dedupjob -Volume <VolumeLetter> -Type Unoptimization
> ```
>
> Check the status:
>
> ```
> get-dedupjob
> ```
>
> Clean up the Garbage:
>
> ```
> start-dedupjob -Volume <VolumeLetter> -Type GarbageCollection
> ```
>
> Check the status:
>
> ```
> get-dedupjob
> ```

Comment: Data Deduplication feature is not enabled on our server. The situation is more like the first case. The file is stored by FreeFTPd.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the folder which your file is. I tried everting for my 19gb tv series file and didnt work. I accidentally renamed that folder and now everything working